# Additional log output on NUnit test fail

Tags: exception, nunit

Whenever an NUnit test fails *during* its execution (i.e. not when using `Assert.*`), I want to log additional information (I'm writing web tests and I am especially interested in the web page's current DOM).

How to specify a global exception handler in NUnit which is able to log additional information on `NoSuchElementException`s - test should still fail of course.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an NUnit event listener addin that logs the information. See http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunitAddins&r=2.6.3 and http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=eventListeners&r=2.6.3. For a tutorial, see https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/testing-times-ahead-extending-nunit/.